# Changing the size of a column referenced by a schema-bound view in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to change the size of a column in sql server using:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Address]
ALTER COLUMN [Addr1] [nvarchar](80) NULL
```

where the length of `Addr1` was originally `40`.

It failed, raising this error:

```
The object 'Address_e' is dependent on column 'Addr1'.
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN Addr1 failed because one or more objects access 
this column.
```

I've tried to read up on it and it seems that because some views are referencing this column and it seems that SQL Server is actually trying to drop the column that raised the error.

`Address_e` is a view created by the previous DB Administrator.

Is there any other way I can change the size of the column?

Comment: Address_e is a view created by the previous DB Administrator. And like what Remus mentioned, it has SCHEMABINDING defined.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The views are probably created using the WITH SCHEMABINDING option and this means they are explicitly wired up to prevent such changes. Looks like the schemabinding worked and prevented you from breaking those views, lucky day, heh? Contact your database administrator and ask him to do the change, after it asserts the impact on the database.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx):

> **SCHEMABINDING**
>
> Binds the view to the schema of the underlying table or tables. When
>   SCHEMABINDING is specified, the base
>   table or tables cannot be modified in
>   a way that would affect the view
>   definition. **The view definition itself
>   must first be modified or dropped** to
>   remove dependencies on the table that
>   is to be modified.

Comment: thanks Remus, the view does have SCHEMABINDING defined. is there any easy way of bypassing the constrain or do i really need to remove the views to get it working?

Comment: You can't bypass it, that's its whole purpose. Somebody went to extra length to add the schemabindig to prevent table changes. This is not some accident, looks like the person know what was doing. Are you *sure* you want to change the table?

Comment: yes, i'm sure =) and logically (even though i know it doesn't work that way) i'm increasing the length of the column, which should really be fine only if the column isn't dropped and recreated, but unfortunately it's not so... but thanks for your help! =D

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem and unfortunately we are using SCHEMABINDING views in order to index the views. So in my case I'm not using SCHEMABINDING to explicitly block changes to the underlying tables but only to comply with requirements of SQL Server to used indexed views. I would also like to bypass this without dropping and recreating my views.

Answer (score 252):

```
ALTER TABLE [table_name] ALTER COLUMN [column_name] varchar(150)
```

Comment: nah, the problem was like what Remus mentioned. there's nothing wrong with the code itself

Comment: @NilRad Ummm, perhaps you are thinking of PL-SQL? ALTER COLUMN is the  correct syntax on SQL 2008 R2

Comment: Am I missing something? Why so many upvotes? It doesn't answer the question.

Comment: The number of up-votes may be because this question is currently the top [Google hit for 'tsql alter nvarchar length'](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=tsql+alter+nvarchar+length) and thus people (like me) who just want to be reminded how to alter the length of a column see this answer and up-vote it to say "thanks" without spotting (as I did not until reading your comment) that the question is more subtle than the question's title suggests.

Answer (score 6):

If anyone wants to "Increase the column width of the replicated table" in SQL Server 2008, then no need to change the property of "`replicate_ddl=1`". Simply follow below steps --

1. Open SSMS
2. Connect to Publisher database
3. run command -- `ALTER TABLE [Table_Name] ALTER COLUMN [Column_Name] varchar(22)`
4. It will increase the column width from `varchar(x)` to `varchar(22)` and same change you can see on subscriber (transaction got replicated). So no need to re-initialize the replication

Hope this will help all who are looking for it.

Answer (score 5):

See this link

[Resize or Modify a MS SQL Server Table Column with Default Constraint using T-SQL Commands](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/resize-modify-sql-server-table-column-with-default-constraint.aspx)

the solution for such a SQL Server problem is going to be

Dropping or disabling the DEFAULT Constraint on the table column.

Modifying the table column data type and/or data size.

Re-creating or enabling the default constraint back on the sql table column.

Bye

Comment: and schema binding views need to be dropped and re-created.

Answer (score 2):

here is what works with the version of the program that I'm using:  may work for you too.

I will just place the instruction and command that does it.  class is the name of the table.  you change it in the table its self with this method. not just the return on the search process.

---

view the table class

```
select * from class
```

---

change the length of the columns FacID (seen as "faci") and classnumber (seen as "classnu") to fit the whole labels.

```
alter table class modify facid varchar (5);

alter table class modify classnumber varchar(11);
```

---

view table again to see the difference

```
select * from class;
```

(run the command again to see the difference)

---

This changes the the actual table for good, but for better.

P.S. I made these instructions up as a note for the commands.  This is not a test, but can help on one :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the column collation. This script might change the collation to the table default. Add the current collation to the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the size of the column in 3 steps:

1. Alter view `Address_e` and take in comment column `/*Addr1*/`
2. Run your script

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Address]
ALTER COLUMN [Addr1] [nvarchar](80) NULL
```

3. Then again alter view `Address_e`, in order to uncomment column `Addr1`